# Complex sorting and output by values in jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to get a human-readable representation of thread siblings.

I have following output: [output](https://pastebin.com/vJVQSM6L).

```
undercloud) [stack@undercloud ~]$ os baremetal introspection data save compute0 |jq '.numa_topology.cpus[] | select(.numa_node == 0) | .thread_siblings'
[
  11,
  51
]
[
  9,
  49
]
[
  58,
  18
],

....
...
..
.

(undercloud) [stack@undercloud ~]$
```

Common View: [Common view.](https://pastebin.com/qsvwkZyJ)

```
(undercloud) [stack@undercloud ~]$ os baremetal introspection data save compute0 | jq '.numa_topology.cpus'
[
  {
    "thread_siblings": [
      11,
      51
    ],
    "cpu": 11,
    "numa_node": 0
  },
  {
    "thread_siblings": [
      9,
      49
    ],
    "cpu": 9,
    "numa_node": 0
  },
  {
    "thread_siblings": [
      58,
      18
    ],
    "cpu": 18,
    "numa_node": 0
  },
....
...
..
.
(undercloud) [stack@undercloud ~]$
```

I want to get next output:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... etc
40 41 42 43 44 ... etc
```

Is it possible to get such a list using `jq`? Perhaps with subsequent `awk/sed` processing.

P.S.: *JSON moved to pastebin because the stackoverflow engine thinks my post has little detail and a lot of code, but I think I gave a pretty specific question and it doesn't fall into the XY problem.*

Comment: Can you specify your output logic? Describe in words where (exactly) the numbers come from, when line breaks occur, etc.

Comment: @pmf The logic of the output I came here to ask how to get) I have shown what output using jq I have *(see pastebin for more details)* and the question is how to convert these outputs into human-readable output.

Comment: No, by logic I wanted you to describe the factors that influence the output. What might seem trivial to you having a meaningful context for the task at hand, it is not necessarily understandable for others in such an isolated environment as with the question asked. "human-readable" can be many things, and "convert into what I have shown" may also be done by a simple `echo`. I tried to interpret the logic in my answer. Please comment if I misinterpreted it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Look, I have *(look in pastebin)* 40 and 0, and I also have 1 and 41, it's all done very randomly, but I would use `jq` and maybe also `sed/awk` to get to the output that is specified in the body of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
.numa_topology.cpus | map(
  select(.numa_node == 0) .thread_siblings | sort
) | sort | transpose[] | @csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that sorts each `.thread_siblings` array, and then the array of all sibling arrays, transposes it to get all first numbers in one array, and all last ones in another, and joins both with a glue string:

```bash
jq -r '
  [.numa_topology.cpus[] | select(.numa_node == 0).thread_siblings | sort]
  | sort | transpose[] | join(", ")
'
```

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RvfMTT2FrPO)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, here's another way to do it using `--raw-output`.

```
.numa_topology.cpus
| map(select(.numa_node == 0).thread_siblings)
| sort_by(min)
| map(sort)
| transpose | .[] | @csv
```

Example output:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/DDlAD_-ZF47).